# Select Case Statement redundancy -- way to use a recurring expression WITH inequality?

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I'm using SQL server.

I want to use a case statement to quickly 'bucket' a bunch of datediff results.

So---

```
case
when datediff(d,start_time,end_time) > 100 then '100+'
when datediff(d,start_time,end_time) > 50 then '50+'
when datediff(d,start_time_end_time) >= 0 then '0+'
when datediff(d,start_time_end_time) > -50 then '-50+'
...
...
```

Of course the simple case statement cannot be used with inequality typically.
Is there a way to use a variable for this situation? To avoid the typing of the long expression so many times?

How do I avoid the redundancy here, or is it not possible?

Comment: Of course I could do a subquery thing but. Hmm. Maybe that is the best way.

Comment: you are looking for varoables https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way. You could also use a Common Table Expression, but it would make no real difference; it's a matter of style preference.

```
SELECT
    x.name, 
    x.database_id,
    x.create_date, 
    x.diff,
    CASE
        WHEN x.diff >= -50 AND x.diff < 0   THEN '-50+'
        WHEN x.diff >= 0   AND x.diff < 50  THEN '0+'
        WHEN x.diff >= 50  AND x.diff < 100 THEN '50+'
        WHEN x.diff >= 100 THEN '100+'
    END AS thing
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        d.name,
        d.database_id,
        d.create_date,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, d.create_date, GETDATE()) AS diff
    FROM sys.databases AS d
) AS x;
```

Comment: You could do it slightly more simply by inverting... start at `WHEN x.diff >= 100` then the next condition only has to be `WHEN x.diff >= 50`

Comment: @AaronBertrand a wise blogger told me not to trust case expressions 

Comment: I think you meant `MERGE` :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand i wonder how many hours have been spent writing about unreliable features in sql server...